How to send Mail with Dynamic Sender in Laravel 10
I am stuck here I want to send mail in Laravel 10 Mail Class with dynamic email address.I am using Hostinger for hosting & mail both.
I have searched alot but the available solutions they are using techniques which are differ from the way I am sending email.
What I have tried.
I have dynamically passed the FROM ADDRESS & NAME but it because it does not match my .env username then it gives error <from email>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user <email used in .env>".
I want when I someone contact me from my website I receive mail from his/her email on my server I hope I expalined my issue clearly. If someone knows about it Please guide me.
Thanks.

"I want when I someone contact me from my website I receive mail from his/her email" - your server is not allowed to send emails for just any arbitrary email address your site visitor might enter. As our "classic" on the topic, PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail explains: "Don't use a faux From: sender" Send from an email you are allowed to send for, and put the site user's email into Reply-To, in case you want to be able to respond to those mails directly from within your mail client.

Did you mean LIKE THIS ??.
return new Envelope(
replyTo: [
new Address('taylor@example.com', 'Taylor Otwell'),
],
subject: 'Order Shipped',
);

It work for me when I put replyTo I am able to reply directly from my webserver Please post your solution as answere then I will accept it.
